# Changing CSS margin in jquery as a negative percentage

Tags: jquery

I have this in CSS:

```
.inner{ margin-left: -100% };
```

How would I assign this in jquery?

```
$('.inner').css("margin-left", -100%);
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$('.inner').css("margin-left", "-100%");
```

Answer (score 1):

Include quotes or double quotes around the value.

```
$('.inner').css("margin-left", "-100%");
```